# R studio not auto completing. New install

Tags: r, autocomplete, rstudio

I've just had my IT department install R and R studio. However it isn't autocompleting. This isn't the end of the world but it's very annoying. Is there anything that I can do to rectify?

I have it on another machine here and it works (but that cannot download certain packages so I know it's possible in the company)

Let me know if there are certain things that I should add to the question to help you help me. 
Cheers, 
J
PS I can't access stackoverlow from work right now ( it thinks there's a virus in the site. So this has been posted on my phone and so it might be poorly formatted)

> sessionInfo()

R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)

Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:

[1] LC_COLLATE=German_Germany.1252  LC_CTYPE=German_Germany.1252    LC_MONETARY=German_Germany.1252

[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=German_Germany.1252

attached base packages:

[1] grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:

[1] CHAID_0.1-2    partykit_1.0-5 ROSE_0.0-3

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):

[1] splines_3.1.2   survival_2.37-7 tools_3.1.2

Comment: Have you checked the respective options under Tools > Global Options > Code > Completion?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I did look but can't see the option under code editing (or any other option in global options)

Comment: rider "Completion" in the code section of your Global Options. There is "Editing" "Display" ... "Completion"

Comment: In my version, there isn't. I'm clicking global options, there's code editing and nothing about code completion.

Comment: Great that this seems simple but I don't know why I can't find it. I'm in r studio rather than r. Thanks for taking the time to help me

Comment: I've just looked on another r session and seen what you mean. Seems that this wasn't the case on r3.1.

Comment: Sorry for the frequent posts. I keep trying to press return and posting accidentally on my phone. The obvious answer is to update to latest r. However I had issues with 3.3 and downloading some packages, so I want to know if there is another option first. Where can I find these options on r3.1

Comment: I would expect that this is a Rstudio issue rather than an R issue right?  I've tried to do it myself and despite the install suggesting it completed, it hasn't.  So I've contacted IT but just wondering if it's R rather than R studio.  Any thoughts?